# Not Been able to connect to JNDI while Upgrading to JBoss 7.1 and Hibernate 4.0

Tags: hibernate, jboss, upgrade, jboss7.x

We are in a process of upgrading our servers from Jboss 5.1 to Jboss 7.1 Final. But not all the servers will be moving to the new Technology at once.

I am upgrading the first server on Hibernate 4.0 and Jboss 7.1. But was not been able to connect to the Datasource located on the Other Jboss Server (5.1) via JNDI.

Data Source (*-ds.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/wc-mysql</jndi-name>

    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://XXX:3306/wellclub</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
    <user-name>myclub</user-name>
    <password>myclub</password>

    <exception-sorter-class-name>
          org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.MySQLExceptionSorter
    </exception-sorter-class-name>

    <!-- The minimum connections in a pool/sub-pool. 
         Pools are lazily constructed on first use -->
    <min-pool-size>50</min-pool-size>
    <!-- The maximum connections in a pool/sub-pool -->
    <max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
    <!-- setting java context as Global so outsider can also use it. -->
    <use-java-context>false</use-java-context>
    <metadata>
       <type-mapping>mySQL</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/wc-mysql</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jndi.url">jnp://jndi.wellclub.me:1099</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jta.UserTransaction">UserTransaction</property>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And in Hibernate Utility class I am initiating the SessionFactory as

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

// Add all the Annotated classes here...

ServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new ServiceRegistryBuilder();
builder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
serviceRegistry = builder.buildServiceRegistry();

sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry); <== Error
```

**Exception:**

```
03:28:01,820 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/core]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.wellclub.service.WCStartupService: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [jdbc/wc-mysql]
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:68) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2273) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2269) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1738) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    at com.wellclub.model.util.ParentHibernateUtil.initiateSessionFactory(ParentHibernateUtil.java:131) [wc-model-2.3.0.jar:]
    at com.wellclub.model.util.HibernateUtil.initiateSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:32) [classes:]
    at com.wellclub.service.WCStartupService.contextInitialized(WCStartupService.java:44) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc/wc-mysql -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jdbc.wc-mysql
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:178)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:113)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:396) [rt.jar:1.6.0_26]
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:65) [hibernate-core-4.1.1.Final.jar:4.1.1.Final]
    ... 24 more
```

Error Line

```
org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [jdbc/wc-mysql]
```

Please tell me what I am missing. If I am doing it the correct way please I would like a guidance as well.

Answer (score 0):

I notice 2 things which might be the cause,

```
 1. <use-java-context>false</use-java-context>   - set it to true

 2. hibernate.jndi.class is different for Jboss 4 and 7 atleast.
```

those things may do the trick..

But I strongly suggest you, create the local datasource on JBoss 7.

- Maddy

Comment: by setting `use-java-context` to `true` would make the JNDI only visible for the local java context. So i need that to be available globally.

Answer (score 0):

may be you should try looking up for the datasource jndi name like this

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:jboss/datasources/jdbc/wc-mysql</property>
```

in the Jboss server admin console , under the profile tab

in the Connectors -> DataSources section the JNDI names of the datasources are listed

Comment: `datasource` is not located in the current JEE Context. So i need define the JNDI name without `java://` and has to provide `JNP` URL to get locate the resource.